# How to write into the CoreData entity at the same index in different view controller (also swift files)

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I have created core data using 'NSFetchedResultController' and 'managedObjectContext' in a table view. But in the later view controller, after gathering accelerometer data and conduct calculation, I will get some results that I also want to store in the same row index with the core data I created before.

How can I achieve this? If I create managedObjectContext again, it will create another 'row' of core data in this table.

The code in tableViewController:

'
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

```
var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
    fetchedResultController.delegate = self
    fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)

}

func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: trialFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultController
}

func trialFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Trials")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    return fetchRequest
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = fetchedResultController.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!
}

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
return numberOfRowsInSection!  
}

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let trial = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Trials
    cell.textLabel?.text = trial.trialName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = trial.date?.description

    return cell
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let managedObject:NSManagedObject = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject

         managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(managedObject)
         managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
    }

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
        tableView.reloadData()
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showTrial" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let trial:Trials = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as Trials

        let trialController:TrialDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TrialDetailViewController

            trialController.trial = trial
      }

    }
```

'

The code in the createTrial Controller:

'      let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "createTrial"  {
        if theTrialName.text != "" {
            createTrial()
        } else {

            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Trial name couldn't be empty", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}

func createTrial() {
    let entityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Trials", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let trial = Trials(entity: entityDescripition!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    trial.trialName = theTrialName.text
    trial.location = theLocation.text
    trial.notes = theNotes.text

    if theArm.on {
        trial.arm = 1
    } else {
        trial.arm = 0
    }
    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
}
```

'

ps. the view controller I want to get data from is not this following segue, it is around 3 view afterwards. And I have created a string to store the data I need in that view.

Comment: Pass the context you already have?

Comment: Hi, it is a normal table view core data. I've updated the code. And the data I get afterwards, I would like to put it in the same 'row' of core data in the table cell, and I can show it in a detailViewController by clicking the cell. How should I get access to write in the same row of core data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating the object in the `tableViewController`and use `segue` twice to transmit it to `secondViewController`and `thirdViewController`. So it will be at the same index for the whole time. And I can change the content of the core data at both the following view controllers.

Comment: Thanks for another help from this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888633/how-to-write-into-the-coredata-entity-at-the-same-index-in-different-view-contro)